# Fried 3way Stereo/8track/Record player with original wiring and need advice on what items are compatible to use

Tags: capacitor

I have an old Magnavox 3 part cabinet that was fried and does not operate anymore. I took it apart to see what the damage was and will have to replace come fried wiring and potential fuses and capacitors. I need some guidance on what capacitors are compatible with the equipment as the ones used have been discontinued. The markings are +/-10% 100v7346 and I have attached a picture below, its the grey one. If you need more pics let me know

So far I have replaced some wiring and was able to turn on the stereo but no sound comes through and no power is sent to the rest of the machine. [image]

Comment: 7346 is likely a date-of-manufacture: not likely related to capacitance. But it IS likely 100 volt. These capacitors are less likely to die from old age, compared to those big electrolytic aluminum cans.

Comment: ^^^ What Glen said.  Those are mylar film capacitors -- Unless damaged by extra high voltage application, or maybe by water or mechanical means, they will last just about forever.  The big blue EL caps are the ones that have an actual aging mechanism and likely are no good.   You can only tell if the caps (either kind) are good by removing them from the circuit to test.   In general I might add, the 'shotgun approach' to equipment repair can cause more problems than it solves.   Troubleshoot it, don't just replace everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for free schematics. Measure all obvious DC voltages and check  audio contact switches for corrosion by contact cleaner, or tapping on them to see if they make a sound.  See if Audio Amp works at all by tracing backwards and forwards for signals.

RTFM https://www.repairfaq.org/sam/audiofaq.htm

Caps are general purpose same C and V or higher from a Japanese source like Nichicon can be tested in some cases in circuit with an LCR meter, but usually not.